# Dynamically select columns in LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, dataset

Similar question exists but solution does not apply.
I'm finishing a small program that allows user to import 2 data tables and join to get results. Here's relevant code:

```
List<DataRow> list1 = ds1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList<DataRow>();
            List<DataRow> list2 = ds2.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList<DataRow>();
            var v = (from t1 in list1
                     join t2 in list2
                     on t1.Field<string>(ds1ColInx) equals t2.Field<string>(ds2ColInx)
                     select new
                     {
                         t1,
                         t2
                     }).ToList();
```

But this can't be fed into `DataGridView`, quite obviously. Now, I also have a `string array` of column names and column indexes for each table and column that user wants to see. How can I plug that into `select` statement?

Comment: *"this can't be fed into DataGridView, quite obviously"* -- that's somewhat less obvious to me. Can you expand on that? Anyway, on to your real question: Why is LINQ a requirement?

Comment: This might address your needs, however: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: "Similar question exists but solution does not apply" Are there any specific questions you can refer to? I'm pretty sure this has been covered before.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I would guess that the problem with binding that result to a DataGridView directly is the anonymous type, which is not "flat."  The columns would just be the "ToString" of the two types (t1 and t2), rather than the properties of those two types.

Comment: @jadarnel27 You're right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring in the Microsoft-developed "System.Linq.Dynamic" library to accomplish your goal.  You can find it on NuGet here:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/

And the source is here:

https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic

Then reference System.Linq.Dynamic, and you will have access to new extension methods that accept strings rather than expressions.

I have only every used it with the lambda-based LINQ extension methods, which enable you to do things like this:

```
.Select("column1, column2, column3").ToList();
```

I have attempted to rewrite your query using the lambda syntax below, although it is untested:

```
var v = list1.Join(
            list2,
            t1 => t1.Field<string>(ds1ColInx),
            t2 => t2.Field<string>(ds2ColInx),
            (t1, t2) => new {t1, t2});

v.Select(columnList).ToList();
```

Note: in this situation, you may need to play around a bit with your column strings (for instance, I think you'll need to prefix them with "t1" or "t2" depending on which table they are actually in).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest converting `v` to a `DataTable` and copying the columns desired. Using `cols` as your desired columns:

```
string[] cols;
var dt = new DataTable();
var t1cols = ds1.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(dc => dc.ColumnName).ToHashSet();
var tcols = t1cols.Cast<DataColumn>().Union(ds2.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()).ToDictionary(dc => dc.ColumnName);

foreach (var cname in cols)
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(cname, tcols[cname].DataType));

foreach (var vr in v) {
    var nr = dt.NewRow();
    foreach (var cname in cols)
        nr[cname] = t1cols.Contains(cname) ? vr.t1[cname] : vr.t2[cname];
    dt.Rows.Add(nr);
}
```

Now you can just assign `dt` to `GridView.DataSource`.

Note that bad things will happen if `t1` and `t2` have any columns with the same name, in which case you should rename them all with a table prefix in `t1cols`,  `tcols` and when adding them to `dt.Columns`.